# Using jQuery's method .ajax() to send a form in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm currently working on a form that allows the user to change their password. And I'm not very good with jQuery ajax. The ajax doesn't seem to send the data to changepassword.php. The PHP file works fine when I don't use ajax. Can you guys help me out here a bit?

I updated my files according to some of the comments. When I try to submit the form, it returns `Doesn't Work`. So I guess the php is responding, but the value didn't get to the database.

Thanks a lot for the help guys.

Following is the form and ajax (Updated)

```
        <form id="form_id" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required />
            <label for="old_password">Old Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" required />
            <label for="new_password">New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" required />
            <button class="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
            <p class="result"></p>
        </form>
        <script>
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache : false
            });
            $(".submit").click(function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "changepassword.php",
                    type : "POST",
                    data : $("#form_id").serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        if(data == 1) {
                            $(".result").html("Works");
                        } else {
                            $(".result").html("Doesn't Work");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        </script>
```

And this is `changepassword.php` (Updated)

```
    <?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
include_once "../classes/Connect.php";
$connection = new Connect();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
$new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
$result = $connection -> change_password($username, $old_password, $new_password);
if ($result) {
    echo 1;
}
    ?>
```

This is the method `change_password()` from `connect.php` class file

```
    function change_password($username, $old_password, $new_password){
    $query = "UPDATE Account SET password = ? WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    if ($stmt = $this -> conn -> prepare($query)){
        $stmt -> bind_param('sss', md5($new_password), $username, md5($old_password));
        if ($stmt -> execute()){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on firebug?  Do you get alert as "Works"?

Comment: echo $username or whatever in your php file then alert(data); instead to see if its passing over to the php correctly.

Comment: I the alert "Works" doesn't show up. I tried to echo $username in php file, but it doesn't pass back to ajax. And I don't quite know how to use firebug

Comment: Just for kicks, also add `$.ajaxSetup ({cache:false})` at top of your script.

Comment: In Firefox: Open Tools->Web Developer ->Firebug->XHR Tab.  Then click your button and examine/click the console contents.

Comment: I used Firebug, when I click submit.
The content in Profile shows "GET http://localhost/Test/change.php?username=ql9da&old_password=74108520&new_password=123456"
But I was passing the data in POST

Comment: You have to take a look at what's happening inside XHR tab, this will show if the ajax request fires, and if it failed or not

Comment: The script tag I put inside <head>, so before <form>

Comment: Also, try handling the error and complete ajax events: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

Comment: Instead of using $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']); wouldn't it be better to use $username = $_POST['username']; ??

Comment: I had that before. It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Is your request to the server successful? Because I'am not sure but if the entire request fails then u don't have success and jquery ajax (probably) will look for error function but you didn't provide it - so nothing happen'.

About setting your ajax data property probably u can do `data: $('#form_id').serialize()` and thid=s will create proper string for request - var1=value1&var2=value2 but with less code.

If there is problem in your php file after `session_start();` inserting the following code  will give you a hint what's going wrong:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Wish you luck.
Ivelin

Comment: I did that. And I also gave an id to the form. But it's still not working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: In your case 'Doesn't Work' mean that request is successfully sended to the script, but something in mysql request or logic goes wrong. If you can check the result of query with  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php